# Are there genealogy related institutions in Greece?

Tags: greece

Are there any genealogy related institutions in Greece to help with genealogical research?

I am trying to gather information on ancestors from Asia Minor.

Comment: Are you in Greece looking for information about ancestors in what is now Turkey?  Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: @Jeni That's right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *Foundation of the Hellenic World* has undertaken the work of preserving the personal and family memories of Hellenism and presenting them to the future generations of Greeks. Through the personal and family history of every refugee, from Asia Minor, Black Sea, Eastern Thrace or Constantinople, they try to reconstruct the character of Hellenic presence both within and outside the present day borders.

Make sure you check the following web pages:

- http://www.genealogies.gr
- http://www.fhw.gr/depts/genealogy/

They have even published a book titled *"After the Catastrophe. Asia Minor refugees in Greece in the Interwar Period"*. It is a collective publication by FHW, which was published under the auspices of the Hellenic Parliament and examines the presence and historical development of the Asia Minor refugees in Greece in the period between the two World Wars.

Answer (score 4):

There is the Genealogy project of the Genealogy and Oral History Department of the FHW in Athens. I am the head of the department. Please contact us via e-mail.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your answer. Complete answers are more useful -- you could provide the contact email address or a website.